ForceAtlas2 and Nooverlap configuration graphology & sigma.js
I'm using the graphology and want the graph to keep the communities together but communities should be very spaced away from each other, also the nodes shouldn't be stuck together so the labels are still readable when user zooms in. My graph is usually very interconnected so it's hard to balance it. Nodes that aren't connected shouldn't be in the center clumped together either.
Ideally no nodes' labels should overlap each other but I'm not sure how to achieve that.
I'm looking into layout-forceatlas2 and layout-nooverlap as web workers, but unsure how to configure the settings properly most things I tried don't achieve the result I'm looking for
Could you share some configuration or insight on how to achieve this graph layout?
Thank you

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
